# Eclipse RCP: How to programmatically create file/folder in workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Project is developed for Eclipse Luna. I tried to programmatically create file/folder in workspace using code

```
try {
    fd.create(true, true, null);
}
catch (CoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here fd is an instance of IFolder. Code is triggered by a test button on a custom view. After clicking the button, I could see the new file/folder created in the directory tree displayed on the custom view. I checked the local file system and the newly created directory is there. The problem is if I re-run the project, the directory is not shown up in the directory tree.

I tried to use this code before loading the directory tree to check the synchronization state:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().isSynchronized(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE)
```

And it always returned false. I tried to refresh local then

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
```

But that worked only for the current debugging/running process. That is, the next time I run the project, method isSynchronized(int) returns false again.

Any suggestions about this problem? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: The `create` call is the correct way to create a folder and is used in many places in Eclipse. Are  you sure the workspace is being closed correctly when your RCP closes? Are there any messages in the .log file?

Comment: You saved me again! The problem is fixed after putting ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().save(true, null);  in the program shut down logic. Thank you very much.